# how to get data Pair array list in android?

Tags: java, android

give Exception:

```
 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
             at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next
```

CODE

```
public ArrayList<Pair<Sticker, Integer>> undoStickerView() {
    return UndoSticker;
}
for (Pair<Sticker, Integer> s : undoRedoStickeriView.undoStickerView()) {
    stickerView.addSticker(s.first);
    undoRedoStickeriView.addRedoStickerList(s.first, s.second);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that you should not modify a container/list while you are iterating using a for-each loop over it.

Possible solutions:

- iterate using a for-loop using an `int` as index iterator
- iterate over a copy of your container/list and then apply the changes to the original container/list